# Where are the pages for the Statistics module shown?

Tags: nodes

I've installed the Statistics module (version 7.18) in my Commerce Kickstart 2 store, but I can't find it anywhere in menu.

What should I do to access this module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After enabling the statistics module, be sure to configure the module (admin/config/system/statistics).

The [documentation for the statistics module](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/statistics) indicates that:

> To enable collection of statistics, the Enable access log checkbox on
>   the Statistics settings page must be checked. This access log is used
>   to store data about every page accessed, such as the remote host's IP
>   address, where they came from (referrer), what node they've viewed,
>   and their user name. Enabling the log adds one database call per page
>   displayed by Drupal.
>
> The Discard access logs older than setting on the settings page
>   specifies the length of time entries are kept in the log before they
>   are deleted. This setting requires a correctly configured cron
>   maintenance task to run.
>
> Enable Count content views to turn on and off the node-counting
>   functionality of this module. If it is turned on, an extra database
>   query is added for each node displayed, which increments a counter.

After configuration, data will begin to be collected for the four reports that statistics provides:

- Recent hits (admin/reports/hits)
- Top Pages (admin/reports/pages)
- Top Visitors (admin/reports/visitors)
- Top Referrers (admin/reports/referrers)

*NOTE:* This applies to all Drupal 7 installations.  Statistics is a [core module](http://drupal.org/node/1283408) and is not specific to Commerce Kickstart 2.